# best design of parent-child process communication with a database

Tags: c#, database, wcf, ipc

Suppose we have parent process, `A`. `A` recives the input `username` and `password` and looks them up in a `AllUsers` database to make sure the `username/password` combination are valid. `A` then starts a new child process `B` and passes it the `username/password`. `B` needs more info from the database, such as the user's `age` and `nickname`.

**Should `A` only be allowed to have database access:**

- `A` gets all the info from the
  database and passes it all to `B` via
  command line strings when it creates
  the new `B`.  Even though `A` doesn't
  care about `age` and `nickname`. `B` would parse the strings to grab the fields.
- `A` only passes the
  `username/password` to `B`, and `A` has WCF
  services that lets `B` call the
  services, which makes `A` access the
  database and return the info to `B`.

**Should `A` and `B` both have database access:**

- `A` only hands `B` the
  `username/password` and lets `B`
  access the database so it can get the
  `age/nickname` itself.

**Should we have multiple databases:**

- `A` only has access to the `AllUsers`
  database. But we also have a database
  for each user. So, 10,000 users =
  10,000 databases. `B` accesses only
  the one user database for the one
  user it cares about.

Keep in mind there will only be one `A` but there could be hundreds or thousands of `B` processes. I want to keep the load as even as possible, ie, I don't want `A` to be a bottleneck if thousands of `B`'s need to talk to it. But I'm also concerned about having two processes access the same database at the same time, seems like it might cause slow access or corrupt data.

These are the ideas I have for how to go about this. Which one is the best? Or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion username and password should not be transmitted by any means if possible and it seems that it's quite easy to avoid it in your scenario. First of all no process should have full access to the `AllUsers` database because it keeps security sensitive data. A good approach would be to use a stored procedure that only `A` have access, to pass username and password (hash) as parameters. This way if process `A` gets compromised, the attacker cannot simply get  a list of usernames and passwords. He/She could try to brute force but with adequately secure passwords (and proper monitoring) you should have more than enough time to spot the event. If they are correct the stored procedure should return a cryptographically secure random session token. This should be the only piece of information to pass by and the way you do it (WCF, command line argument etc) is not important, choose whatever you like. Process `B` should be able to query whatever information it needs through stored procedures that take the token as parameter and return filtered results based on your needs. For example process `B` should be able to read only its own user row but without the password. Add some finishing touches like a job to clear old sessions and you have a design that it's both secure and easy to maintain.

Comment: Even though the original post was more about scalability, I agree that security should be considered at this point in the design.  I would suggest never storing the passwords in the database at all.  Just store a one way hash of the password with a unique salt per record and then even if your database is compromised, the passwords are still safe.

Comment: This brings up an interesting question. Where should the passwords be stored if not in the database? Might have to ask another SO question.

Comment: @jb: To be a secure basis for authentication, passwords should be stored in 'wetware' between their owners' ears, and nowhere else. That is why Diadistis and Brent advocate storing a salted hash, not the password itself.

Answer (score 1):

Databases were designed to handle multiple simultaneous access.  Unless you are doing something strange, then I don't see why A and B shouldn't have access to the database(s) if your primary concern is avoiding bottlenecks.

I would avoid having a database per user, as you are probably going to be running many if not all of the instances on the same machine.

I would suggest reading up on database capabilities and scaling.

Hope this helps.